# Keras - Train convolution network, get auto-encoder output

Tags: python, keras

What I want to do:
I want to train a convolutional neural network on the cifar10 dataset on just two classes. Then once I get my fitted model, I want to take all of the layers and reproduce the input image. So I want to get an image back from the network instead of a classification.

What I have done so far:

```
def copy_freeze_model(model, nlayers = 1):
    new_model = Sequential()
    for l in model.layers[:nlayers]:
      l.trainable = False
      new_model.add(l)
    return new_model

numClasses = 2
(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test) = load_data(numClasses)
#Part 1
rms = RMSprop()
model = Sequential()
#input shape: channels, rows, columns
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                        input_shape=(3, 32, 32)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#output layer
model.add(Dense(numClasses))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=rms,metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(X_train,Y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=25,
          verbose=1, validation_split=0.2,
          callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)])
print('Classifcation rate %02.3f' % model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)[1])

##pull the layers and try to get an output from the network that is image.

newModel = copy_freeze_model(model, nlayers = 8)
newModel.add(Dense(1024))

newModel.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=rms,metrics=["accuracy"])
newModel.fit(X_train,X_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=25,
          verbose=1, validation_split=0.2,
          callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)])
preds = newModel.predict(X_test)
```

Also when I do:

```
input_shape=(3, 32, 32)
```

Does this means a 3 channel (RGB) 32 x 32 image?

Comment: I think it might be not the best idea to reproduce a convolutionaly transformed image by a noconvolutional layer.

Comment: @marcin what would you suggest I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest you is a stacked convolutional autoencoder. This makes unpooling layers and deconvolution compulsory. Here you can find the general idea and code in Theano (on which Keras is built):

https://swarbrickjones.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/convolutional-autoencoders-in-pythontheanolasagne/

An example definition of layers needed can be found here :

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/378